# How to create a complex filter from a single value passed in from USERNAME() function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am generating `Power BI` embedded tokens for Row Level Security.

The token contains a value of a role for the `USERNAME()` function to receive, which is then used in the Table filter DAX expression, e.g.: `[Region] = USERNAME()`. This works when a value (say `West`) is passed in from the token, and the sales report will be filtered by the `West` Region.

Next, I need to add additional filters like: `[Region] = USERNAME() && [Customer] IN {"Delta", "Echo"}`. I've tried to pass in `West|Delta|Echo` to USERNAME() and changed the DAX expression to:
`[Region] = LEFT(USERNAME(), FIND("|", USERNAME())-1) && [Customer] IN {"Delta", "Echo"}`

This version worked, but the list for IN filter had to be hard-coded.

Is there a way to write a DAX expression to extract multiple values delimited by `|` and create a list for the `IN` operator shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have a table in the middle, and then link the appropriate fields to that table, so West|Delta|Echo would be 2 rows: West, Delta and West,Echo. Then this table has relationships (one directional) to the Region and Customer tables.

In line with what you are currently doing, and if there are no overlaps between the Customer entries (e.g., no Echo and Echo2), you can use `CONTAINSSTRING(USERNAME(), [Customer])`

Comment: Luckily, there are no overlaps. Your solution is brilliant!

Comment: Well, while there are no overlaps right now, there is no guarantee there won't be in the future as new customers are added.  @JoaoLeal Could you provide a sample DAX expression to split a string by "|" to populate rows in a table?

Comment: Add a calculated column called Customer Piped = "|" + [Customer] + "|", then on your security string make sure it ends with a pipe as well. And finally do the containsstring against your new calculated column.

Comment: I made a small tweak using Customer Marked = "^" & [Customer] & "^" and passed in West|^Echo2^ and it filtered out Echo.  Thanks a lot!